# Scaffolding fails because RazorPageWithContextTemplateModel doesn't contain a definition for ViewName?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, scaffolding, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project that was working fine with scaffolding until I upgraded to .NET Core 2.1.  Now, when I try to scaffold, I get the following error:

```
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageWithContextTemplateModel' does not contain a definition for 'ViewName'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

Google doesn't give me much info, and the error doesn't even point to a specific file in my project.  I searched all instances of ViewName in the templates, and it's only used in the context of @Model.ViewName.  Not really sure where to look from here.  Any ideas?

Maybe my templates are out of date?  But then, where can I get new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out there is no ViewName for Razor Page Templates in 2.1.

You need to do a Find & Replace on all files in the \Templates\RazorPageGenerator\ folder from "Model.ViewName" to "Model.RazorPageName".

After that, my scaffolding worked great.  But I do wish the initial error pointed me to the actual problem a little better.